# Can't execute a php prepared statement

Tags: php

The code I can't get to work should do the following things:

1. Read SQL statement from file
2. Make a prepared statement out of it
3. Execute the prepared statement

**Non-working code:**

```
    $sql = file_get_contents($root . '/data/init.sql');
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn);
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
```

**Working code**

```
$sql = file_get_contents($root . '/data/init.sql');
$pdo = new PDO($dsn);
$result = $pdo->exec($sql);
```

Please point out the mistake in the *non-working* snippet of code.

Comment: Add error checking or look in your error logs.

Comment: In what way does it "not work"?

Comment: Can you show us your query ?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but where do you bind the parameters??

Comment: @Akintunde there aren't necessarily any parameters. Actually, based on the working code, I'd say there must not be.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Then what is the reason for preparing the query?

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton I don't know. There's not much information here.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton That's why i've "cut to the point". Anyways it's not like with any additional info it will transform to a complicated problem.

Comment: @VladLyga additional info might transform it into an answerable question, though.

Comment: @Don'tPanic - extrapolate. this is obviously someone learning the PDO api.

Comment: @Don'tPanic As far as I know, there is no reason to ever prepare a statement that has no parameters. Am I misinformed?

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton It isn't necessary, but that doesn't mean it won't work.

Comment: @Don'tPanic But if there are no variables then this is a non-issue, there is no reason to prepare the statement. As OP said, the exec() code works. If there are supposed to be variables, _there are none supplied_, which may break the query. I think that Vlad's answer may be a correct assumption of what is going on, but we need more information.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton I think that his problem is that he tries to prepare (negotiate with the database) a query for a schema that doesn't exists. That is the problem

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton there aren't any variables supplied in the working code, so it seems there aren't any. But the question is why it won't work as a prepared statement, which can't be answered without more information.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Looking at your sql file name - i assume you have a DB init script there. 
Maybe for tests.
Anyway, if it's a new database/tables then you cannot prepare query for schema (tables) that don't exist.
The reason is that PDO::prepare is actually needs to negotiate with the database the optimal execution and caching for the query.

Also -  the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) says:

> "Calling prepare [....] for statements that will be issued multiple
>   times with different parameter values optimizes the performance of
>   your application [...]"

And it looks like your init SQL is not parameterized.
So all in all looks like for this specific snippet you don't even need the prepare call.

Drop it.

Comment: you opened my eyes for the root cause! Yes, I have a DB init script in `/data/init.sql` so that's why the whole snippet doesn't work - now I see it, thank you!

Comment: @Nick No problem. Happy to help.